# How can I get exact value from milliseconds using moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I have a code

```
var t = moment.duration(2, "year");
var ms = t.asMilliseconds();

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = moment.duration(ms, 
"millisecond").asYears();
```

his result is "1.9986721151016107"

Thats [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntn1Lvt2/9/)

How can I get the "2" years from milliseconds?

Comment: you will get the result as 1.9986721151016107 because the value is approx 2 years only

Comment: I fear that there is no way yo configure moment to make `asYears()` return rounded values (you can configure [`humanize()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) output, see [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) and [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-rounding/)). In your case you can probably use `Math.round()`.

Comment: There are some issues related to this in the Moment issue tracker, [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3209) and [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4161).

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin.

As has been noted, Moment itself has a number of issues around rounding, floating point, and large-scale unit conversion.

I did a lot of work in my plugin around making sure that you get the expected output in those situations.

```
var t = moment.duration(2, "year");
var ms = t.asMilliseconds();

moment.duration(ms).asYears();
// 1.9986721151016107

t.format("y")
// "2"

moment.duration(ms).format("y")
// "2"
```